# Is there a better way(Performance increase / inbuilt functions) to get the angle of rotation of a rectangle?

Tags: c++, opencv, crop, opencv3.0, rectangles

Current Way to get the angle of rotation.

```
cv::Rect rRect(pTopLeft.x,pTopLeft.y,pBottomRight.x-pTopLeft.x,pBottomRight.y-pTopLeft.y);

img(rRect);

std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = img.begin<uchar>();
cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = img.end<uchar>();
for (; it != end; ++it)
   if (*it)
      points.push_back(it.pos());

cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
double angle = box.angle;

if (angle < -45.)
    angle += 90.;
```

Is there a way to do  avoid for loop and directly get the angle of the Rect using just rRect or are there any inbuilt functions in openCV to get the angle using Rect  ?

Comment: questions asking for "better" ways to do something are off topic as being too vague and opinion oriented.  if nothing else, you need to specify what aspect you wish to be improved - but remember stylistic code reviews are never on topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focused coding problems than this.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more specificc

Answer (score 0):

if we have square points we can do the following.

```
cv::Mat debugSquares( std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > squares, cv::Mat image )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i< squares.size(); i++ ) {
        // draw contour
        cv::drawContours(image, squares, i, cv::Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());

        // draw bounding rect
        cv::Rect rect = boundingRect(cv::Mat(squares[i]));
        cv::rectangle(image, rect.tl(), rect.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, 0);

        // draw rotated rect
        cv::RotatedRect minRect = minAreaRect(cv::Mat(squares[i]));
    cout<<"\nangle"<<minRect.angle;
        cv::Point2f rect_points[4];
        minRect.points( rect_points );
        for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
            cv::line( image, rect_points[j], rect_points[(j+1)%4], cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8 ); // blue
        }
    }

    imshow("  Image", image);
    return image;
}
```

`